# Downloading files for UIWebView to specific folder on IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, download

I have made an app that displays my website from a UIWebView and it takes you to a store that you can download files. My question is that I need to download a '.zip'file from my website using the app to the IPhone. Heres is my problem. I don't want the file to goto the App's Document folder, I want it to goto a folder that is outside of my applications folder. Here is an example path I might want my file to goto EX:'var/mobile/Library/Downloads'. If there is not a way to download the files to a path outside of the app's folder, is there a way to transfer the specific file that I have downloaded from my website using the my app to another folder that is not located in my app's folders? I know this can be done because I have used apps that have done this, of course they were apps only available on Cydia.  This is also an app that will be used for Jail-broken users just for your information! 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "regular" iphone app runs in a sandbox that prevents access to system wide directories. Practically, you only have access to the app Home Directory.

Unless you go for a jailbroken app, you have no other options than storing to the App docs folder.

Read "The Application Sandbox" and "The File System" [here] for more details[1](http://cydia.saurik.com/faq/developing.html).

EDIT:

I am not an expert on cydia, but the general idea is gaining access as root and then write to where you need to. This can be done by replacing your app with a suid shell script that will in turn exec your app (which will have root privileges now and then be able to go out of the sandbox).

For more info look at [this](http://cydia.saurik.com/faq/developing.html).

Comment: So I do have the option to do so if I am making this app for Jail-broken users, then how do I do so?